# Have trouble set the height of the RelativeLayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem to set the height of the ***RelativieLayout*** in Android. I want to change the height of the RelativeLayout to show one ***LinearLayout*** which had been defined already in *.xml* file but set the height to **0** and can't be seen. Here is the details:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <!--Input Block-->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/input_block"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="55dp">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:layout_width="220dp"
                  android:layout_height="55dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="Please input here"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/send_btn"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Send"/>
    </RelativeLayout>  

    <!--File Block-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/file_block"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/input_block"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:visibility="invisible">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/emoji_btn"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                     android:layout_width="30dp"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     android:src="@drawable/emoji"
                     android:background="@drawable/imageBtn_style"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_btn"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                     android:layout_width="30dp"
                     android:layout_height="30dp"
                     android:src="@drawable/imageGallery"
                     android:background="@drawable/imageBtn_style"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Well, in one word, the ***file_block*** had been hide firstly, and I want it will show after the ***edit_ext*** get focused. Here is the core code:

```
private RelativeLayout inputBlockLayout;
private LinearLayout   fileBlockLayout;
private EditText       editText;    

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

inputBlockLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.input_block);
fileBlockLayout  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.file_block);
editText         = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        //editText get the focus to show the fileBlock
        if(hasFocus){   
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, inputBlockLayout.getLayoutParams().height + 30);
            inptlockLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
            fileBlock.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

            fileBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            //editText lose focus to do sth.
        }
    }
});
```

However I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

I don't know where the problem is? Or is there're a good way to set the height of the layout dynamically?

---

**New progress of the problem:**

First,thanks ***@Sagar Nayak*** and ***@Nanoc***! I had applied **Sagar Nayak** good method that solved the original error and can show the ***file_block***, however after that, there're have a little matter that after the show of the ***file_block***, the highest parent layout **RelativeLayout(by id relative_layout in my post code)** changed unexpectedly. In my real project file, the **relative_layout** had been applied **layout_alignParentBottom="true"**, and displayed on the top after the ***file_block*** show.

For more details:

***xml:***

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <!--File Block-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/file_block"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/input_block"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="30dp"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***java:***

```
fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        //editText get the focus to show the fileBlock
        if(hasFocus){
            //inputBlock defined 55dp first, after show the fileBlock it should increase 30dp   
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 85);
            inputBlockLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

            fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm wonder the problem is caused by the method ***setLayoutParams*** of the **inputBlock**. Does anyone have a good idea?

---

**Note:**

Considered that the pop-up of the ***softKeyBoard*** can cause the same problem (applied the property ***android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"*** to the activity in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** no works), so I had add a button to show the ***fileBlock***, give up the original method.

```
<!--Input Block-->
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/input_block"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/add_file_btn"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:layout_width="50dp"
                 android:layout_height="50dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/add_file_btn"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
              android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
              android:layout_width="165dp"
              android:layout_height="55dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="Please input here"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/send_btn"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="Send"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here for the ***.java***:

```
fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
addFileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 85);
        inputBlockLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

        fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

However, there's still have the problem. ( Does anyone have a good way to solve the softKeyBoard pop-up problem and this matter? The two problems really annoyed me. )

Comment: post your whole xml file here after making changes. there might be some problem in xml.

Comment: Hi, @Sagar Nayak! I had checked this problem, it's the ***softKeyBoard*** pop-up after the ***editText*** get focused caused. However, after I applied the property ***android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"***, it still changed the parent layout. So, I had changed my way to show the ***fileBlock*** by click a buton, well, the problem never get fixed.

Comment: so you dont want soft keyboard to pop up ? then when do you want it to pop up ?

Comment: Well, when the ***editText*** get focused, the soft keyboard should pop-up! The problem is, no matter it's the ***editText*** get focused or click the button to show the ***fileBlock***, the parent layout will be changed——never stay at the bottom ( or should adjust the space to fit the soft keyboard when the editText get focused ) , but displayed on the top of the page!

Answer (score 1):

As the logcat error says, file_block its inside a RelativeLayout so you must use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Just change your

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 30);
```

For the next time, LayoutParams apply to the parent view, so if you put a view inside a LinearLayout its params must be of type LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Also maybe you need to call requestLayout() for the changes to make effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much @Nanoc! The problem is really here, the LayoutParams  should apply to its parent view. However, I'm wonder is there any other way to get the effect that I want? Do you have any good idea?

Comment: You are using the correct approach, it would be different if you need to animate the change for example.

Answer (score 1):

first of all check your code in this line -

> inputBlockLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.input_block);

inputBlockLayout is a relative layout.
and input_block is a linear layout .

correct this error and let me know what is the next problem you face.

**Main Problem**

the layout issue you are facing and the solution you are applying is quite applicable but the better way to do it would be-

- make the height of linearlayout in file_block to normal (what you want).

  ```
  <!--File Block-->
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/file_block"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_block"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible">
   ... (this is your code as you posted)
  ```
- then you change this in activity -

  ```
  fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  //editText get the focus to show the fileBlock
  if(hasFocus){  
           fileBlockLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
  }

  });
  ```

**Explanation**

this approach is better then the approach you applied because you are giving space to the element in the layout but just making its height 0dp makes it invisible . and making the visibility invisible also does not take away the element from the layout , it just make it invisible but the space is occupied by the element.

when you make the visibility GONE, then the element is completely taken away from the layout and also it dont take any space until you make it visible.

let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's my misspell mistake. The code that I put here is an example which have the same structure with my real project file. Sorry again, and I had re-edit the content. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, @Nanoc said is right. LayoutParams should apply to its parent view.

Comment: Yes, there's no problem about the **LayoutParams** now according to **Nanoc's** answer, but it's not a good way to show the effect that I want. And I'm thinking a more better method to concrete this, or do you have any good idea?

Comment: from your question what i understand is you have already defined your layout but you dont want to display it. the input block will only be displayed. and when the edittext gets focused then the file block gets displayed . correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Hi, @Sagar Nayak. I had try you way, it's really can show the **file_block**, but however there's comes a matter that the whole layout changed after the **file_block** show —— which means the **RelativeLayout (the highest parent layout, which id is relative_layout in my post code, and defined align parent bottom)** never display at bottom but comes to top of the parent. Why this happen? It's the method LayoutParams applied in a wrong way?

Comment: create chat and lets discuss it there .

Comment: Create chat ? I do not have a good application to suggest, do you have ... ?

Comment: i said create chat in stackoverflow and invite me .

Comment: I had invited you @Sagar Nayak!